# How to test localstorage session/cookie functionality working on desktop browser?

Tags: cordova

I am developing a Cordova mobile application that has login system. How can i test the session/cookie functionality of localstorage on web browser as i am developing mobile app in chrome browser's mobile debug view? Is it possible to check whether it is working or not?

localstorage code is this:

```
window.localStorage.setItem("userid", UserId);
window.localStorage.setItem("username", Email);
window.localStorage.setItem("name", Username);
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

You can have access to the localStorage data from desktop browser.

Run your app on your device and open Chrome. Hit `chrome:inspect` on the URL and select your application from the list. This will open the `developers tools`. Go to `Resources` tab and select `Local Storage` from the options on the left. There you will see the information you store.

Comment: You cannot do it from mobile browser.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can access the localStorage values inside your browser, just go to your browser console and check this:

```
localStorage.userid // This will give you the value in the localStorage
```

Answer (score 0):

that's what I'm doing in my app!

1. try catch the set cookie and/or set item for localstorage.  e.g. store 'hello' to a cookie 'testcookie'
2. try catch a read cookie or read localstorage.  e.g. read the cookie 'testcookie' and set it to a temp var.
3. if the temp var = 'hello', it means that it support cookie and / or localstorage.